# Custom fine-grained claims based authorization system in ASP.NET MVC - wheres and hows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, custom-attributes, security-roles

So, I'd like to implement my own custom authorization system in MVC2.

If I'd have to create a global class, where do I instantiate it?
Can HttpContext be extended with my own additions and where do I do that?
Should I use Authorization filters for rights validation or ActionFilters or do it within an action?
Can ActionFilter pass any data to the action itself?

Previously (in WebForms) I was using a Session object where I would put a serialized object containing essential user data (account id and a list of roles and rights) and I'd extend my own Page class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this thread help?

[How do I create a custom membership provider for ASP.NET MVC 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771094/asp-net-mvc2-custom-membership)