# How to roll out a custom membership system in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I've been reading about overriding the Membership Provider and the Role Provider. I think this is what you need to do when doing Asp.net Form projects. Is this also the way to go with Asp.net MVC projects or there is a better way to do so?

Thanks :)

Comment: So what exactly is your question? How to implement a custom provider? When should you implement a custom provider? Are there practical differences in usage of providers when using MVC as opposed to WebForms? I really can't tell. Here's a tip: One clear question, One clear answer, lots of happy people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the built in membership provider

http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/aspnet35_membership.htm

or create a custom one

[How do I create a custom membership provider for ASP.NET MVC 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771094/asp-net-mvc2-custom-membership)

http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ASP.NET MVC uses the Membership API by default. However, you can always use your own logic if you want to, but most functionality for the Membership API is in there already.

You'll need:

- A custom MembershipProvider
- If you use roles, a custom RoleProvider
- If you use profiles, a custom ProfileProvider