# ASPNET MVC3: Can I use my user/roles tables to handle user authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm building an ASPNET MVC3 app; I have built, on the SQLServer DB, my users, roles and user_roles tables andI would like to use them instead of the aspnet_* tables built by using aspnet_regsql.exe.

Do you know if is this possible and, if so, in which way I can authenticate my users towards my tables?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to implement your own Membership and Role providers.

see [How do I create a custom membership provider for ASP.NET MVC 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771094/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider-for-asp-net-mvc-2)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to [build a custom memberShip provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx)