# Add SqlMembership tables using EF Code First

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm wondering if it's possible to generate the standard MS SQL Server Membership tables (like you would using asp_reg tool) using EF Code First? If so, could you give me the steps necessary to do this?

If not, is my only option to add the tables using asp_reg or the membership scripts to the database created by EF Code First? The problem then would be if I wanted to configure the site to drop and recreate the database on Application_Start, I would lose my membership tables...

Comment: Sql membership provider comes with more than just tables. Do you need just the tables or all db objects?

Comment: @frennky -thanks. I guess I wouldn't be exactly sure (whether I need just the tables or the db objects as well). What would be ideal is whatever would just 'jive' with the built-in SqlMembershipProvider. Thanks, and +1 for raising a good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [EF Power Tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adonet/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released/) to reverse engineer the asp_reg tables into POCOs

[image: Reverse]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-68-19-metablogapi/3618.ProjectMenu_5F00_thumb_5F00_2E36D883.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can have your own table for user, role, and userroles by creating custom membership provider. Have a look at 
[How do I create a custom membership provider for ASP.NET MVC 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771094/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider-for-asp-net-mvc-2)

Comment: -Thanks, I am familiar with creating custom membership providers. But what I was really looking for was more like what qntmfred suggested, and reverse engineering the membership tables into POCOs because that can easily be made into a reusable component. Thanks anyway.