# ASP.Net MVC Forms Authentication and membership provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, form-authentication

In ASP.Net MVC, are the Forms Authentication and Membership Provider tightly coupled?
The Membership provider model is very different than the existing user validation services that I already have that I need to integrate with. I would like to write my own class to manage users, but still use the built in forms authentication and forms cookie to allow a logged-in user to access authenticated sections of the website.

Can I just delete the reference to the MemberShipProvider from web.config and call my own custom class from the controller I use to validate users? Will Forms Authentication still work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either create a custom membership provider as @negadro mentioned or just call the [SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx) after your custom validation.

```
//your custom validation logic here
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, rememberMe);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom membership provider. This answer will help you , i think. [How do I create a custom membership provider for ASP.NET MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771094/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider-for-asp-net-mvc-2)