# Using the same database for data and membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-membership

I have an `MVC 4` application that uses `Entity-Framework` and `SQL Express 2008`, and i want to use the same database also for membership and roles. my connection string is:

```
 <add name="AuthTestDbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=AuthTestDb;user id=sa;password=1234;pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and so i added another connection string for the membership:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AuthTestDb;user id=sa;password=1234;Integrated Security=True"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and i ran the `aspnet_regsql.exe` command so it added the necessary tables to my database.

However, if I add a new user using the `ASP.NET configuration` tool I cannot log in with that user and i can't find him in my database. If i create a new user using the register action i can log in with it but it creates a new database in my `App_Data` folder called `ASPNETDB.MDF`.

What do i need to do so that i'll be able to use the same DB for my website?

Comment: @Downvoter - down voting is OK but explaining why is even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Option: Consider looking at a Custom Membership provider and create only the tables/columns you need to support your own application.

I am sure there are a lot of examples if you search for Custom Membership provider, here is one: [How do I create a custom membership provider for ASP.NET MVC 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771094/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider-for-asp-net-mvc-2)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! i actually ended up using [this](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/entity-framework-queries-involving-many-to-many-relationship-tables/) and [this](http://kitsula.com/Article/Custom-Role-Provider-for-MVC).