# How to authorize user's role in asp.net using custom database?

Tags: asp.net

Sorry if my title's question is not clear. The thing is in my asp.net application I config web.config of folder "Admin" like this:

```
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow roles="Admin" />
          <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

My database has an table "Account" with 3 fields (Username, password, role). Then I use the login control to login the site of folder "Admin" using code:

```
    protected void Login_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
      if(checkUser(Login.Username, Login.Password))
        e.Authenticated = true;
    }

    private bool checkUser(string username, string pass)
    {
      // Check username and pass against database....
    }
```

The problem here is that I do not know how to tell the web.config file that the user has "Admin" role.
I can fix this problem by using aspnet_regsql which automatically generates several tables in my database, then I log in successfully using Membership.ValidateUser. However, I do not know what happens underground using these built-in database and features. That's why I wonder if it can be solved using custom database above.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried searching the net for Creating a Custom Membership Provider? Sounds like that's what you want to do.

Comment: This post deals with creating a customer membership provider. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771094/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider-for-asp-net-mvc-2